# Questions to build a dynamic dataTable Java

Tags: java, jsf

I need to build a dynamic dataTable, which carry an object from the database with the following structure:

I need to build a dynamic dataTable, which carry an object from the database with the following structure:

Object:

- Name = Ana
- Cpf = 12364547

I need this data to be displayed in two columns, for example:

column 1

- name
- cpf

column 2

- Ana
- 12364547

I have the following code:

```
public void criarTabelaDinamica(Object obj){
        fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        this.tableMensagem = (HtmlDataTable) fc.getApplication().createComponent(HtmlDataTable.COMPONENT_TYPE);

        HtmlColumn column1 = new HtmlColumn();
        tableMensagem.getChildren().add(column1);

        HtmlColumn column2 = new HtmlColumn();
        tableMensagem.getChildren().add(column2);

        tableMensagem.setValue(obj); //how to put the items in the two columns of the object? Here is my question!!!
    }
```

note: The object varies on the amount of items in my example are 2, you may have 5 for example.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you really need to create a dynamic table? Maybe you could use nested `<ui:repeat>` to create it in the Facelets code.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendonza Could you give me an example?